# reading gctx file in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read a gctx file extracted from LINCS source for gene expression analysis. The codes for eading the file are provided at the link below.
https://github.com/cmap/l1ktools.
I am using the script provided and I have sourced the script. however when I tried the function `parse.gctx` it gives me following error:

```
ds <- parse.gctx("../L1000 Data/zspc_n40172x22268.gctx")

reading ../L1000 Data/zspc_n40172x22268.gctx
Error in h5checktypeOrOpenLoc(file, readonly = TRUE) : 
  Error in h5checktypeOrOpenLoc(). Cannot open file. File 'C:\L1000 Data\zspc_n40172x22268.gctx' does not exist.
```

How can I resolve this issue and read my gctx file?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're getting a 'file does not exist' error, I think the problem is because you have a space in the path to the file you're trying to read (specifically, in "L1000 Data"); if you remove the space in the path it should parse properly.

In other words, try renaming your "L1000 Data" folder so that instead of:

```
ds <- parse.gctx("../L1000 Data/zspc_n40172x22268.gctx")
```

you have something along the lines of:

```
ds <- parse.gctx("../L1000_Data/zspc_n40172x22268.gctx")
```

Comment: Hello, please add some detail to your answer so that it would be clear and easier to understand.

Comment: Details added! Let me know if anything's still unclear.

Comment: Looks much better, thank you for adding more detail. For future reference, pleas take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, which has great tips for writing good answers.